# How to create overlapping images using CSS

Tags: css

I have created 5 images overlapping each other but I am stuck on this part
("Whenever the mouse is placed over any of the images that image must move to the front of the group and be the primary image on display. When the mouse has pulled away the image will return to its original position")

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a :hover pseudo class in CSS you can set the z-index of an image to greater than the other images.

When the hover class no longer exists the img will go back to its original position.

This snippet uses z-index: 1 as the default is 0.

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
}

img:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50px;
}

img:nth-child(3) {
  left: 100px;
}

img:nth-child(4) {
  left: 150px;
}

img:nth-child(5) {
  left: 200px;
}

img:hover {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1015/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1016/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1018/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1021/200/300">
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1023/200/300">
```